# Getting CommandLineArgs StartsWith Failing

Tags: vb.net

[image]I've got an application.  I haven't had to use command line arguments before but my research suggests my method isn't wrong.  In VS2015, in my project properties->debug I've added `/boxID=123` but when I debug, I get nothing in my inputVal variable.  Where am I going wrong?

```
Imports Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word 'needed for COM object interaction with MS Word
Imports System.Data.SqlClient 'needed for DB interactions
Imports System.IO 'needed for BLOB

Public Class Window
    'set form level declarations
    Dim appPath As String
    Dim objWordApp As New Word.Application
    Dim objDoc As Word.Document

    Function boxIDfromCommandLine() As Integer
        Dim inputArg As String = "/boxID="
        Dim inputVal As String = ""

        For Each s As String In My.Application.CommandLineArgs
            If s.ToLower.StartsWith(inputArg) Then
                inputVal = s.Remove(0, inputArg.Length)
            End If
        Next

        If inputVal = "" Then
            inputVal = "0"
        End If

        boxIDfromCommandLine = Convert.ToInt32(inputVal)

    End Function

    'form load subroutine
    Private Sub Window_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        'Establish application path, replace appPath on deployment
        Dim appPath As String = Application.StartupPath()

        'Run application in foreground or background.  
        'If in background (false), be sure to add objDoc.close() and objWordApp.Quit()
        objWordApp.Visible = False

        'Declarations
        Dim localDateTimeString As String = DateTime.Now.ToString
        Dim localDateTimeFileName As String = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddhhmm")
        Dim soNumber As String = "No_SO_Selected"
        Dim boxID As Integer = boxIDfromCommandLine()
        Dim saveString As String 'file name format
        Dim savePath As String = "C:\ITO_PackingLists" 'set folder location
        Dim connection As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection() 'set SQL server connection string
```

...
...
...

Comment: Did you debug this code? What is the exact value in CommandLineArgs? Can you explain better where do you add the /BoxID=123?

Comment: The code actually seems to be failing in `If s.ToLower.StartsWith(inputArg) Then ...`  If I set a watch on the CommandLineArgs property, I can see that the first element is the entire argument I set in the debugger `/boxID=123`.

Comment: inputArg is correctly showing `/boxID=`

Comment: And that's exactly what you should expect. The commandline is simply broken up on the spaces and each part is considered an argument.  It's up to you to break up something like "/boxID=123" yourself.

Comment: @jmcilhinney which is what I expect my if statement should be doing.  Obviously the element is there, but why does the if statement reject the comparison, when the comparison is actually correct?

Comment: `s.ToLower` can never match `"/boxID="`, since it has upper case characters in it.

Comment: @Mark Yeah I JUST saw that. lol  Sorry!  Bonehead me.

Comment: You should always avoid using `ToLower` or `ToUpper` for case-insensitive comparisons if possible.  `String.StartsWith` already has an overload that lets' you specify that the comparison should be case-insensitive so you should use that.